# Struggling to understand why joins/includes are needed with Rails when an association exists in the model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to create a very complicated query and am having troubles with it - so I'm going back to the basics to try and figure out what I'm missing.
I've been reading the `Rails Guides` for `Active Record Associations` and `Active Record Query Interface` (specifically [section 12](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) - joins) and I'm failing to understand how they are related and why joins/includes are needed.

The Associations page says "With Active Record associations, we can streamline these - and other - operations by declaratively telling Rails that there is a connection between the two models."  Section 12.2 of the Query page says "Active Record lets you use the names of the associations defined on the model as a shortcut for specifying JOIN clauses for those associations when using the joins method."

These two statements seem somewhat at odds with each other to me.  If I create as belongs_to association why do I need a join if I'm trying to pull data from both tables?  Looking at it another way:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

If I do `@orders = Order.all` I can output the customer name by doing `@orders.first.customer.name`.  However, if I want to select all orders with 'smith' in the name I would do something like `@orders=Order.where('customer.name ilike "%smith%"').joins(:customer)`

How is it that this "relationship" is working in first half, but requires the join in the second half?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to join, however until you call your association your data will not be loaded.

This is a quality of `ActiveRecord::Base` called lazy loading.

You can see this in the SQL output from your console.

```
user = User.find(1)
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

This particular user model has over a hundread association.

Why are none being loaded?

Because we haven't called them yet.

```
user.articles
Article Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`user_id` = 1
```

Now we see the query is executed.

In sequence this becomes a problem when working with plain old Ruby.

For example, consider the following:

```
users.each do |user|
  puts user.articles.first.title
end
```

Running the following code is problematic, because every time Ruby iterates over a user, it calls the articles for only that user.

You end up querying for each user repeatedly which performs the following SQL:

```
Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`user_id` = 2 LIMIT 1
Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`user_id` = 3 LIMIT 1
Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`user_id` = 4 LIMIT 1
Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`user_id` = 5 LIMIT 1
Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`user_id` = 6 LIMIT 1
etc.
```

We can solve this by loading all of our data initially within a single query.

```
users.joins(:articles).each do |user|
  puts user.articles.first.title
end
```

Which will perform the following SQL before the enumeration begins:

```
Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`user_id` IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc.)
```

This is where `ActiveRecord::Base` methods like `includes` and `joins` come into play.

Here are two good articles on the matter:

http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

https://rubyinrails.com/2014/01/08/what-is-lazy-loading-in-rails/

Comment: great description!  You've really helped to bridge the gap for me.  Also, that first article really gave my new information - I never understood how to mix and match all the relationships.  Hopefully this will help me get my query back under control, and let me get the results I'm looking for. :)

Comment: does the order of the lazy-loading matter `select.preload(articles).last` vs `select.last.preload(articles)`?

Comment: Yes, preloading can only happen on a scoped section. So for example: `User.joins(:articles).each`. You must load directly off a scope otherwise it will fail, probably with undefined.